# how to call the Add,Subs, Div and Display function

Tags: c

```
typedef struct 
{ 

    void (*Add)(int,int);
    void (*Subs)(int,int);
    void (*Div)(int,int);
    void (*Display)(void);
} Calculator;

typedef struct CalculatorData
{

    Calculator*  data;
}CalculatorData;

static CalculatorData aritmaticOperation = {

    .data= NULL
};
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't tag both unless you're asking about the differences between them. (This must be C.)

Comment: You'll need to set `arthmeticOperation.Calculator` to be a pointer to an initialised Calculator object, but then you can call `arthmeticOperation.Calculator->Add(2,3);` etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Don't just dump code and assume the title tells all. Ask a question.

Comment: OK, I'll answer next time, then.

Comment: Above are the edited code

Answer (score 1):

The `Add`, `Subs`, `Div` and `Display` members are not functions.  They are pointers to functions and in the `aritmaticOperation` object in the code presented, they are not initialised - there is nothing to call.

Given a suitably initialised `aritmaticOperation` object, you would call `Add` for example by:

```
int result = aritmaticOperation.data->Add( x, y ) ;
```

However in this case data is NULL, so the above would result in run-time error.

You need a `Calculator` object, with the member pointers set to *actual* functions:

Given say:

```
int MyAdd( int a, int b ) { return a + b ; }
```

and similar for the other operations, then

```
static Calculator MyCalculator = { MyAdd, MySub, MyDiv, MyDisplay } ;
static CalculatorData aritmaticOperation = { .data= &MyCalculator } ;
```

then:

```
int result = aritmaticOperation.data->Add( x, y ) ;
```

will effect a valid call to `MyAdd()`.